# Implode no me funciona PHP

Tags: php, array

```
if( count($usuario['info']['cv']['habilidad']) > 0 && isset($usuario['info']['cv']['habilidad']) && $usuario['info']['cv']['habilidad']){
    $html .= '<div style="font-size: 16px; border-bottom: 1px solid #999999; color: #F29222; font-weight: normal;"><img src="img/curriculum-04.png" width="20" align="middle"> Habilidades</div>';
    $html .= '<div>'.implode(", ", $usuario['info']['cv']['habilidad']).'</div>';
}
```

Error:

```
Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in /main.php on line 1438
TCPDF ERROR: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
var_dump :
array(2) { [0]=> array(5) { ["id"]=> int(212) ["habilidad"]=> int(7) ["usuario"]=> int(5000) ["documento"]=> string(0) "" ["otro"]=> string(0) "" } [1]=> array(5) { ["id"]=> int(213) ["habilidad"]=> int(2) ["usuario"]=> int(5000) ["documento"]=> string(0) "" ["otro"]=> string(0) "" }}
```

Comment: La variable `$usuario['info']['cv']['habilidad']` debe contener un array.

Answer (score 0):

El error (al menos el que te marca) es el count, no en el implode. Otra cosa es que además (a raiz o no) de ese count, te esté dando otro problema en el implode.

No obstante, antes de comprobar si el count es mayor que cero, deberías comprobar primero si el array/objeto existe, ya que sino, en el caso de no existir, también te soltará un error porque tratará de contar los elementos o propiedades de algo que no esta definido. Es decir:

En lugar de hacer esto:

```
...count($usuario['info']['cv']['habilidad']) > 0 && isset($usuario['info']['cv']['habilidad'])...
```

deberías hacer esto:

```
...isset($usuario['info']['cv']['habilidad']) && count($usuario['info']['cv']['habilidad']) > 0...
```

Al margen de esto, prueba a hacer un var_dump sobre la variable para que veas exactamente que tiene.

```
var_dump($usuario['info']['cv']['habilidad']);
```

---

### **UPDATE**

Vale, pues creo que ya lo tenemos. Lo que creo que te está ocurriendo es que tu array está compuesto de elementos que son arrays, no strings/ints/etc... y lo que espera la función implode es que se le pase un array cuyos elementos sean strings/ints/etc..

Es decir:

```
$a = array('a','b','c','d');
echo implode('|',$a) //sacará por pantalla a|b|c|d
```

Pero en tu caso tienes algo asi como:

```
$a = array(array(5),array(5));
```

por eso cuando va a "unir" ambos elementos del array principal, se encuentra con más arrays y eso "no lo puede unir" y darlo como bueno, y de ahí que te suelte el warning. Basicamente te está diciendo: "yo lo he unido, pero cuidado porque lo que he unido son arrays".

Probablemente lo que buscas es un implode de cada uno de los valores de esos arrays internos. Como no estoy seguro del todo de lo que quieres sacar por pantalla, podrías ponerme un ejemplo simple de lo que esperas obtener por favor?

Comment: he añadido mi var_dump a mi pregunta