# ¿Cómo poner varios id de un modelo en una sola cadena de texto separada por ; o cualquier otro simbolo en PHP?

Tags: php, string, caracteres

Tengo un array del cual tengo que obtener todos los id y llevarlos a una sola cadena de caracteres, por ejemplo, tengo los siguientes id:

```
$array = [25671, 25672, 25673, 25674];
```

Y necesito esto:

```
$ids = "25671;25672;25673;25674";
```

Esto porque estoy usando una API que nos ofrece una empresa y así debo enviar los id de los recursos. He intentado de varias formas, en js ya lo hice, pero desconozco un poco las funciones básicas que trae PHP. Estaría agradecido si alguien me orienta un poco.

Comment: Revisa [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/219574/54039), seguramente te servirá.

Answer (score 0):

Lo más simple que se me ocurre, es concatenar al recorrer ese array...

En este caso, recorro leyendo el array, y lo concateno a un string 
Para luego agregar el valor del array, pero como es int, hay que pasarlo a string, sino saldrá el error de NAN.
Finalmente, el punto y coma.

```
$array = [25671, 25672, 25673, 25674];
$ids = "";
foreach ($array as $a) {
    $ids.= strval($a) . ";";
}

var_dump($ids); //string(24) "25671;25672;25673;25674;"
```

---

El uso de `implode()` mencionado por Triby en los comentarios, seria lo siguiente para tu caso.

`implode()` lo que hace, es unir los elementos de un array, a un string, agregando un separador entre ellos.

```
$array = [25671, 25672, 25673, 25674];
$ids = implode(";", $array);
var_dump($ids);
```